# Fn + Right Arrow on MacBook Pro does not work as END Key for SuperUser web site

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, macbook

I am using a MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.5. I am new to this development environment, and previously worked on Windows.

I have tried that <kbd>Fn</kbd> + Right Arrow on Mac works as <kbd>End</kbd> key on Windows — which makes cursor move to the end of line, for most application like Word for Mac — I have tried it works. But I tried Fn + Right Arrow does not work for current question input box of SuperUser.

I am wondering how to solve this issue and why? Does anyone have the same issue for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's different on Mac. Generally, <kbd>End</kbd> (and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + Right) will scroll to the bottom of the page. To go to the end of the line, use <kbd>Command</kbd> + Right.

If there are exceptions like Word, it's because they deliberately change the key behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Or, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>e</kbd>   for end of line, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>a</kbd>  for beginning of line.

Comment: This works only in Terminal though